# How do I change the TextEdit document background color in macOS Ventura?

Tags: color, textedit, multitasking

Since updating from Mojave to Ventura, some of my TextEdit documents no longer have a background color and some do.

I'd like to set a background color again. Apple mentions, in the [Ventura TextEdit support pages](https://support.apple.com/nl-nl/guide/textedit/txte2be20f33/1.17/mac/13.0), in the Font panel, a document color button, but on my screen it is missing from.

Is there still a way to set the background color in TextEdit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can only change the background colour in an RTF document (one where you can change the fonts). If your TExtEdit is set to 'text', hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to toggle to rich text.

Then in menu Format > Fonts > Show Fonts (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
[image]

you get a pop-over panel where on the top you find a little "a" (normally on white background).
[image]

Select that and a colour panel comes up
[image]

Click a colour and you have a new background
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Looking back I almost can't believe why I didn't understand it right away.

Comment: No problem. I don't think it's super intuitive. Almost as if Apple forgot.